# Where a particular equation meets a particular axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

The question asks where the tangent plane to $z = e^{x - y}$ at $(1,1,1)$ meets the $z$-axis. Without performing any computations or even looking at the given function, based solely on the question "where does an arbitrary function of $x$, $y$, and $z$ meet the $z$-axis," isn't the answer at when $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, so the answer is: at $(0,0)$ on the $xy$-plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To, to say where an object "meets the $z$-axis", one must specify at what point on the $z$-axis the object intersects it.  (You do not waste the reader's time telling him that the $z$-axis is all the points with zero $x$ and $y$ coordinates.)  For the plane $1$, it meets the $z$-axis at $1$.  Given a plane, one can find where it meets the $z$-axis by setting $x = y = 0$ in the formula for the plane and thereby finding the height of the plane where it is intersected by the $z$-axis.